# How to set the value of ApplicationResource.properties with a value from database table?

Tags: database, jsp, properties, localization, struts2

I have  a page with a file name

**`login.jsp`:**

```xml
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Struts 2 - Login Application | ViralPatel.net</title>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Struts 2 - Login Application</h2>
<s:actionerror />
<s:form action="login.action" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="username" key="label.username" size="20" />
    <s:password name="password" key="label.password" size="20" />
    <s:submit method="execute" key="label.login" align="center" />
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I have an `ApplicationResource.properties` that looks like this :

```
label.username = Username
label.password = Password
label.login    = Login
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to replace those with values from database.

Suppose i have a table that looks like this :

```
|id  | resource_key     | msg           | 
| 1  | project.username | Your Username |
| 2  | project.password | Your Password |
| 3  | project.login    | sign in       |
```

so the ApplicationResource.properties is going to be like :

```
resource_key  =  msg    ( but not hardcoded )
```

for example  :

```
project.username = Your Username
project.password = Your Password
project.login    = sign in
```

if it is possible , how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

By default a text provider is using keys from the properies files.

You should create a custom text provider and add it to `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.xworkTextProvider" value="com.example.CustomTextProvier"/>
```

The class `CustomTextProvier` should implement `TextProvider`. When implementing `getText` methods you can write a code that accesses a database and returns required values.